# java: Single socket on read write operation. Full duplex

Tags: java, sockets, duplex, socketchannel

I have to implement sending data with specific source port and in the same time listen to that port. Full duplex. Does anybody know how to implement it on java. I tried to create separate thread for listening on socket input stream but it doesnt work. I cannot bind ServerSocket and client socket to the same source port and the the same with netty.
It there any solution for dull duplex?

```
    init(){
    socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(Target.getHost()), Target.getPort(), InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 250);
    in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    }

     private static void writeAndFlush(OutputStream out, byte[] b) throws IOException {
        out.write(b);
        out.flush();
      }


    public class MessageReader implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
//this method throw exception EOF
          read(in);

          }
private void read(DataInputStream in){
 while (isConnectionAlive()) {
          StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();
          byte[] b = new byte[1000];
          while ((b[0] = bufferedInputStream.read(b)) != 3) {
            strBuf.append(new String(b));
          }
          log.debug(strBuf.toString());
        }
}
        }
```

Comment: When you write to a specific port it's not `your` port.. you are writing to the target machines port unless you are saying you are writing to yourself?  Start with the Listener...

Comment: new Socket(remoteAddress, remotePort, localAddress,               localPort). I need listen on local port and in the same time send messages from that port. ServerSocket cannot send messages. Plain Socket cannot listen or at least I dont know how to implement it

Comment: You only need one socket for reading and writing. You can call [Socket.getInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream()) for reading and [Socket.getOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream()) for writing. However, reading from the input stream is a blocking call, so you may wish to do it in a separate thread. Show us some of your code so we can see what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is quite strange: A `ServerSocket` is a fully implemented socket that accepts connections, it handles its own messages and you definitely cannot piggy-back another socket on top of it.

Full duplex is fairly simple to do with NIO:

1. Create a `Channel` for your `Socket` in non-blocking mode
2. Add read to the interest OPs
3. Sleep with a `Selector`'s `select()` method
4. Read any readable bytes, write any writable bytes
5. If writing is done, remove write from interest OPs
6. GOTO 3.
7. If you need to write, add bytes to a buffer, add write to interest OPs and wake up selector. (slightly simplified, but I'm sure you can find your way around the Javadoc)

This way you will be completely loading the outgoing buffer every time there is space and reading from the incoming one at the same time (well, single thread, but you don't have to finish writing to start reading etc).

Answer (score 1):

I had run into the same question and decided to answer it myself. I would like to share with you guys the code repo. It is really simple, you can get the idea to make your stuff work. It is an elaborate example. The steps accidentally look like Ordous's solution.

https://github.com/khanhhua/full-duplex-chat

Feel free to clone! It's my weekend homework.

Answer (score 0):

Main thread:

- Create background thread(s) that will connect to any target machines(s).

  - These threads will connect to target machines and transmit data and die
- Create an infinite loop

  - Listen for incoming connections.

    - Thread off any connection to handle I/O

Classes:

- Server

  - Listens for incoming connections and threads off a Client object
- Client

  - This class is created upon the server accepting the incoming connection, the TcpClient or NetClient (i forget what java calls it) is used to send data.  Upon completion it dies.
- Target

  - Is created during the start up and connects to a specific target and send data.
  - once complete it dies.

Comment: I dont send reply to client. I should be able send message to any server and listen to prt which i used for sending my message

Comment: ok, is the list of servers you connect to and send data known?  i assume it would have to be

Comment: lets assume we have some server called Target with known targetHost and targetPort. I  connect and send messages to Target with connection like new Socket(remoteAddress, remotePort, myHost, myPort) and vice versa Target sends to my port myPort so I must listen to myPort all the time. It's not request-reply  communication . Target and me send messages to each other in random order

Comment: sounds straight forward...  main thread a listener... then spawn off a thread to connect to this "target"...

Comment: do you mean  new ServerSocket(myport) and create listener? Then how to  send message to specific port without prior request? I cannot create another Socket on the same local port

Comment: yes... then upon a connection you thread that off to handle the i/o, the main thread needs to be in a loop that just accepts connections.

Comment: you send messages to these targets using their own thread...  I will pcode it in my answer..  gimme a few.

Comment: In such case issue with sending messages. I cannot create another socket with the same localport and dont know how to send message with existing server socket to my Target without prior request from Target

Comment: so the target will connect to you and identify itself?  still not a problem, use that information and connect back

Comment: i never suggested you create more than 1 socket for listening, you can only have one listener for a port...  I don't think you are understanding what I'm telling you..

Comment: Target doesn't connect to me I have connect to Target and use proper localPort otherwise Target will reject me. It's not request-reply communication at all.

Comment: I cannot create server and client, it should be only one socket

Comment: ok, but you would know the port..  the port is on the target not you.. what is the issue?

Comment: I cannot create server and client, it should be only one socket –

Comment: yes, server listens for connections... are there not going to be incoming connection requests?

Comment: if I create server I cannot send my messages without request from Targer but i have to

Comment: you haven't explained it well at all... this is wasting my time...  you should be able to explain in more clarity...

Comment: Yes you can... you can create a server and connect... why do you think you cannot?