# How to automatically update server and client side in java

Tags: java, sockets, distributed-system

I'm learning distributed systems basics and currently I'm trying to do a simple yet realistic messenger between **one** server and **one** client. **What I do intend is that on each endpoint socket side (Server and Client) text automatically updates (like a real "messaging app")**. In other words, I want that the moment I write and "send" the message, it automatically appears on recipient side. What I have now follows this schema:

1. I send a message (let's assume from client)
2. To see that message on Server's side I need to reply first (because Server's BufferedReader / Client's PrintWriter is only read after asking for the answer)

My code:

```
public class ClientSide {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        String host_name = args[0];
        int port_number = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        try {
            Socket s = new Socket(host_name, port_number);

            PrintWriter out =
                    new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);

            BufferedReader in = 
                    new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader stdIn = 
                    new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(System.in));


            String answer;

            while ((answer = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
                out.println(answer);
                System.out.println("\nlocalhost said\n\t" + in.readLine());
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClientSide.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}


public class ServerSide {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int port_number = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port_number);
            Socket tcp = ss.accept();

            PrintWriter out = 
                    new PrintWriter(tcp.getOutputStream(), true);

            BufferedReader in =
                    new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(tcp.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader stdIn = 
                    new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            String answer;
            while ((answer = stdIn.readLine()) != null){
                out.println(answer);
                System.out.println("\nClient said\n\t" + in.readLine());
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerSide.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this? Does it involve advanced knowledge on the matter?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is already answer for  such question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512053/java-single-socket-on-read-write-operation-full-duplex and answer from Khanh Hua looks good check his  repository https://github.com/khanhhua/full-duplex-chat

Answer (score 0):

The core problem is that you want to wait for two events concurrently -- either a message from the socket, or input from the user!

You want to wait on both at the same time -- you don't want to be stuck waiting for a message in the socket if the user types a message; nor to be waiting for the user message while you have a new message from the network.

To 'wait' for messages from multiple streams, you have [java.nio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_(Java)). I believe it is the most *correct* way of doing it.

But if you want to keep using the `BufferedReader`, there is a `ready()` method that returns `true` if and only if there is a message waiting to be read.

Your code after the `in` and `stdIn` declarations would then look something like (I didn't test it!!):

```
while(true) {
    if(stdIn.ready()) {
        System.out.println("I said " + stdIn.readLine());
    }
    if(in.ready()) (
        System.out.println("He said " + in.readLine());
    }
}
```

A few somewhat useful random links:

- [Java - Reading from a buffered reader (from a socket) is pausing the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328125/java-reading-from-a-buffered-reader-from-a-socket-is-pausing-the-thread)
- [Is there epoll equivalent in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621783/is-there-epoll-equivalent-in-java)